# How to customize the item selection animation on listView in Metro Style App?

Tags: listview, coding-style, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a listView. When I click on one of the item, there is an animation associate with it: ie, the item become smaller and pop up again. How do I customize the animation? Can I make the item flip instead? or can I just take off the animation, and not doing anything?

Thanks,

Comment: Note of course that customizing the animation means that your program no longer conforms to Metro design guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the visual states of the ListView, in particular the SelectionStates VisualStateGroup.  Have a look at [this discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/a428be57-e76d-404c-be15-8c6105ea217c).  There is also a styles sample in the SDK which shows how to override this.